# Windows 2008 server hosting in Europe

Tags: windows-server-2008, hosting, virtualization

I'm searching for a Windows 2008 server in Europe, preferably in Germany or UK or anything with good routing to Denmark (as its where the primary traffic will be generated from).

The server will be used as web server (asp.net mvc, php), mail server and database server. We are running a few sites with around 200 concurrent users, which isn't much, but we intend to expand in the near future and the server should be easy to scale in form of adding more RAM and HDD space - if its possible.

I think a virtual server may be the best choice - hyper-v or virtuozzo? - considering cost vs specs - but i'm open to suggestions.

The max budget is in the range of $1000-1200/year.

You guys have any suggestions? Let me know if you need further info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this: http://english.keyweb.de/